# curl not overwriting header fields

Tags: perl, curl

I've encountering an issue where the endpoint server is returning a '417 Expectation Failed' error after 1024kb has been sent.  I don't believe curl is rewriting the headers appropriately before the request is sent to the endpoint.  I am using the -H flag and been reading over many different threads, to include the curl manpages, in an attempt to understand what I may be doing wrong.

I'm writing in Perl.  Here is how I am setting my headers.

```
my $curlpath   = "/usr/local/bin/curl";
my $xml        = #-- yes, xml is really passed but i omitted it

push @curl_vars, "-H 'Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:'"; #-- header flag
push @curl_vars, "-v"; #-- verbose mode
push @curl_vars, "-d"; #-- data flag
push @curl_vars, $xml; #-- data
push @curl_vars, $endpoint;

eval
{
    #-- command line execution
    open (FILE, "-|") || exec $curlpath, @curl_vars;
    $response = join '', <FILE>;
    close (FILE);
};
```

Here is the trimmed curl response from the log.

```
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > Host: myhost.com\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > Accept: */*\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] >  'Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:'\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > Content-Length: 1069\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > Expect: 100-continue\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] > \r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] * HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] < HTTP/1.0 417 Expectation Failed\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] < Connection: close\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] < Content-Length: 18\r
[Fri Oct 10 16:04:36 2014] < \r
```

Comment: as per the http spec "the server MUST response with a 417 if any of the expections cannot be met". If ANYTHING goes wrong with the upload, then its hould be responding with an error code, but you're only expecting/allow a 100-continue, so it HAS to respond with 417. e.g. if it always dies after 1024kb, then that strongly suggest you're exceeding a 1meg file upload limit, but the server can't tell you that, because you're not allowing it to

Comment: @Marc B, the OP is trying to clear the Expect header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *change* one header and *remove* another one, so invoke curl with two -H uses:

```
 -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -H 'Expect:'
```

That is, each -H changes a single header so you need one -H for every header you want to modify.

Combined with the error ikegami pointed out, that means you'd need

```
push @curl_vars, '-H', 'Content-Type: text/xml';
push @curl_vars, '-H', 'Expect:';
```

Answer (score -1):

When you say

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:'
```

you call `curl` with two arguments.

- `-H`
- `Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:`

In your Perl code, however, you pass single argument.

- `-H 'Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:'`

Perhaps you need

```
push @curl_vars, '-H', 'Content-Type: text/xml; Expect:';
```

There could be other problems.